# PHP zip archive adds extra folder

Tags: php, zip, directory, absolute

I have a piece of code which generates a .zip archive containing all files and folders from a given folder. It looks like this:

```
function zipDirectory($source, $destination, $flag = '')
{
if (!extension_loaded('zip') || !file_exists($source))
{
    return false;
}
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if (!$zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE))
{
    return false;
}
$source = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($source));
if($flag)
{
    $flag = basename($source) . '/';
    //$zip->addEmptyDir(basename($source) . '/');
}
if (is_dir($source) === true)
{
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        $file = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($file));

        if (is_dir($file) === true)
        {
            $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $flag.$file . '/'));
        }
        else if (is_file($file) === true)
        {
            $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . '/', '', $flag.$file), file_get_contents($file));
        }
    }
}
else if (is_file($source) === true)
{
    $zip->addFromString($flag.basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
}
return $zip->close();
}

zipDirectory($downloadID.'/','temp_'.$downloadID.'.zip', false);

$zip_file = 'temp_'.$downloadID.'.zip';
$file_name = basename($zip_file);
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $file_name);
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($zip_file)+15);
```

However, the resulting .zip archive ends up containing the specified folder, as well as an extra folder called "C:" with folders inside it, making up the absolute path to the root of my site. There are no files in this chain of folders.

I don't really know what could be causing this... Any ideas? Would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you working on a windows server? I've modified your script and this is the [result](http://pastebin.com/UjwBen94). For me it works when setting `$downloadID` to current dir. Please make sure what your current dir is. I'm using linux.

Comment: I'm on Windows yeah. When I remove the str_replace's, the chosen folder will be zipped into the absolute path, instead of just to the root of the .zip archive.